# Alamofire requst taking around 10 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've run this code on my mac with good wifi and my phone using wifi / data and I'm getting an extremely slow load time on the code below. It takes about 7-10 seconds for my UI to update which I do in my view controller in the second block of code where the ...'s are.

This isn't the first time I've dealt with web requests and I've never had this kind of slow behavior. It is the first time I've used Alamofire and this kind of completion handler stuff I'm doing in my downloadProfileInformation where DownloadComplete is a typealais for () -> ().

I figure maybe the problem lies there. It's not updating the UI until everything is completely downloaded I guess, but should a picture be taking 10 seconds to download?

[image]

https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/game/unlocks/0x0250000000000BB0.png

This is an example of a link that could be grabbed from the API.

I also don't know if it's possible the issue is with the API? I've never heard of something like that but I don't know what's possible.

https://api.lootbox.eu/documentation

EDIT:

```
//Called with IBAction



PROFILE_URL = "\(URL_BASE)\(Info.sharedInstance.platform)/\(Info.sharedInstance.region)/\(Info.sharedInstance.battletag)/profile"

Alamofire.request(PROFILE_URL).responseJSON { response in
    let result = response.result

    if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {

        if let error = dict["error"] as? String {
            print(error)

        } else {

            if let data = dict["data"] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                //Assigning variables to that value
                if let username = data["username"] as? String {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.battletagNameOutlet.text = username
                  print("battletag update happening")
                                }
                }
                if let level = data["level"] as? Int{
                ...
                }

                if let avatarURL = data["avatar"] as? String {
                ...
                }

                if let competitive = data["competitive"] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                    ....
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You are updating UI  from the backgtound thread. Your request is fine but your completion handler is not. There are multiple similar questions here.

Comment: @Sulthan - Alamofire runs its completion handlers on the main thread for you, unless you manually specify some other queue for the completion blocks to be run on. With `NSURLSession`, your point would be well taken, but it's generally not a concern with Alamofire.

Comment: Hibernia, the only thing that jumps out at me is that you're running consecutive requests, so any network latency is going to be multiplied. If you can design this to work with a single request, or concurrent requests, you'll yield performance improvements. I'd suggest you refine your debugging to identify what portion of the delay happens where, and then you'll be able to tackle the redesign from there. But you want to update the UI as responses are received, not waiting for everything. BTW, you're not doing any synchronous requests (e.g. `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`) anywhere are you?

Comment: @Rob I'm not doing any synchronous requests anywhere. This might have been super unnecessary, but I just moved everything out of the class and popped it in the main View Controller and scratched the "completed" bit.  When I'm grabbing values like level from my dictionary I'm updating the UI and wrapping that i a DispatchQueue.main.async, but everything is still trying to update at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the loading takes more time if the Per_Page is more than 50 for your API link. This can cause a delay when dealing with API and requests that contain images and videos.